# performance of loops iterating over selectedItems()

Tags: qt, qgraphicsscene

I had an issue with setting items as selected... so I took a peek at the `QGraphicsScene::selectedItems()` [function](http://cep.xray.aps.anl.gov/software/qt4-x11-4.2.2-browser/d8/d12/class_q_graphics_scene.html#6042e79139b43fb8019336bacaced275).
Ever since, I became really nervous about using it in loops.

In a construct like this:

```
foreach(QGraphicsItem* selectedItem, selectedItems())
{ 
    // perform action with selectedItem
}
```

Will every iteration recalculate the `selectedItems()` function ?
(I think so, because the above becomes unstable if inside the loop I change selection)

I imagine this would have a big impact on my code speed...

So I am starting to change me code everywhere, to:

```
QList<QGraphicsItem*> sel = selectedItems();
foreach(QGraphicsItem* selectedItem, sel)
{ 
    // perform action with selectedItem
}
```

Am I correct in assuming this will speed up the program ?
(or will it make it slower because of copying, while the replacement in loop test would not change, if I am wrong and the `selectedItems()` doesn't really get through all its code ?)

I wonder what other functions should be avoided... like perhaps [`sceneRect()`](http://cep.xray.aps.anl.gov/software/qt4-x11-4.2.2-browser/d8/d12/class_q_graphics_scene.html#37857c479f87f1985437f1aa2a41ab42) or `boundingRect()` for items inheriting from `QGraphicsItem`.... Is it right to copy those to a `QRectF` if used more than once in the same function ?

Comment: The foreach will call selectedItems() only once and keep a copy of the return value, so your second implementation will not speed up the program.

Comment: Also, if you want to speed up a program, I'd suggest to download a profiling tool and use it to locate where the processing time is going before even considering doing anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach(QGraphicsItem* selectedItem, selectedItems())
{ 
    // perform action with selectedItem
}
```

In this case, you're iterating over the returned selected items and as you've discovered, if the selection is changed, this can cause problems.

Is this better?

```
QList<QGraphicsItem*> sel = selectedItems();
foreach(QGraphicsItem* selectedItem, sel)
{ 
    // perform action with selectedItem
}
```

The simple answer is yes.

> will it make it slower because of copying

Not necessarily. If the container is unchanged, it won't make a difference.

However, Qt implements [implicit sharing](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/implicit-sharing.html), which ensures that a container, such as QList will share the data in this case and only make a copy (COW - copy on write), when one of the copies changes.

I wouldn't worry too much over `sceneRect` and `boundingRect`, as they just return simple data types such as `QRectF`, rather than a container of items, so implicit sharing is not required here. Only in extreme circumstances would caching such returned values make a noticeable difference.

Comment: Doesn't implicit sharing mean that the copying will be faster if the container is not changed - but I will not call the function to calculate the selection each iteration - so implicit sharing would mean definitely faster ? .... as for `boundingRect()`, for items like `QGraphicsSvgItem` or `QGraphicsTextItem` that do work to get it, caching to a simple type as `QRectF` instead of calling the function that recalculates the rectangle ....  I assumed them all simple types and once I looked at the code I started worrying. Lol.

Comment: You will not call the function each iteration either way. Look up the docs of foreach. I don't know why the poster said the second implementation is better, both do practically the same thing, except the second one might make an extra (shallow) copy of the list but that would be like one pointer-size of storage so that would be neglectible and propably the compiler will optimize that one away anyway. The only reason it would be better is that it might avoid confusion.